# The correct way to access uncachable memory in Linux

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

My scenario is as follow:

- One board acted as the PCIE Rootport (RP) and one board acted as PCIE
  Endpoint (EP).
- The PCIE Endpoint exported a memory region. This
  memory region is shared between the RP and EP. Whenever we need to
  access this shared memory region (actually we just access the first
  few byte control data structure in this region). We have to do a
  invalidate cache for reading and flush cache after writing.
- I tried to declare the structure as below, but without the invalidate/flush
  cache, the read/write does not take effect.

  typedef volatile struct {
      u32 front;
      u32 rear;
      u32 n_msg;
      u32 offset;
  } queue_ctl_t;

May anyone please tell me the correct way to access this shared memory region. I just wonder how some network drivers (for network cards on PCIE bus) can access the data consistently without doing the invalidate/flush cache.
Any suggestions are appreciated, thank a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `ioremap_nocache()` to map the memory regions in question, and reading/writing them using the `ioread*()` and `iowrite*()` functions.

Comment: hi @caf, thank you for your answer. The problem is definitely the `nocache`. The outbound access should use `ioremap_nocache` and the inbound exported memory region should be allocated with dma_alloc_coherent(). Thanks again!